# Filter string collection based on listview item

Tags: c#, winforms, string, listview, collections

**RESOLVED**

Oddly, it appeared that what was happening here, was that the `string[]` collection was being iterrated through when it had no elements.  Because of that, every single item would be removed from the user list.  Added an additional check to ensure that `nicks.Count !=0`, and it adds and works perfectly.  Have to love when code does things you do not expect ;)

**---[INITIAL ISSUE]---**

So, i'm a bit confused here.

When we connect to our server, we are given a string collection result `string[]`.  We then parse that string collection, and add names to a listview.  However, we need to also parse the listview, and remove any items which do not appear in the string collection.

I can't seem to figure out a way to properly do that.  I know it's easy, but I've failed so far at anything I've tried, which totally isn't cool :(

Code to filter out the string collection to the listview and not add duplicates:

```
foreach (var nick in nicks)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nick)) continue;
            var lvi = new ListViewItem
                          {
                              Text = nick,
                              Group = nick.StartsWith("@") ? listViewEx1.Groups[0] : listViewEx1.Groups[1]
                          };
            if (listViewEx1.Items.Count != 0)
            {
                var foundItem = listViewEx1.FindItemWithText(nick, true, 0, false);
                if (foundItem != null) continue;
            }
            lvi.ImageIndex = 0;
            listViewEx1.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
```

So, how can I conversely compare the items in the listview, with the items in the string collection, and remove those that do not exist?

**Debug Information**

```
Element in 'nicks':   Bot
Element in 'nicks':   Test
Element in 'nicks':   @Mike
Element in 'nicks':   @Jack
Element in 'nicks':   Joe
Element in 'nicks':   Nancy
Element in 'nicks':   Roger
Element in 'nicks':   
Does not contain:  @Mike
Does not contain:  @Jack
Does not contain:  Bot
Does not contain:  Joe
Does not contain:  Test
Does not contain:  Nancy
Does not contain:  Roger
```

So oddly, even though the `nicks[]` collection contains the item, and the `item.Text` contains the nick, the `.Contains()` call is not matching it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are just simple strings then something like this should work:

```
List<ListViewItem> itemsToRemove = new List<ListViewItem>();
foreach(ListViewItem item in listViewEx1.Items)
{
   if(!nicks.Contains(item.Text))
      itemsToRemove.Add(item.Text);
}

foreach(ListViewItem item in itemsToRemove)
   listViewEx1.Items.Remove(item);
```

The reason for the separate remove loop is that you don't want to modify the `Items` collection during an iteration, otherwise you get an exception.

Comment: See, that's what i thought too, i used something a bit different, yet, it removes every item in the list view.  It seems as if the `nicks.Contaions(item.Text)` isn't matching.

Comment: and the confusing part is that `item.Text` is still returning the same elements that exist within the string collection, so i have no idea why the `Contain` isn't matching.

Comment: @zackrspv Recheck my answer, I had a typo in there, not sure if that makes a difference to you or not.

Comment: yeah, it is still removing every element.  I added debug information to my initial question, so that you can see that the `nicks[]` collection does contain information and that the `item.Text` result is returning the same information, but it's not matching on the `.Contains()` check.  Any other options?

Comment: @zackrspv Can you provide the code that you're using to produce that debug information?

Comment: @thedugas  Well if he's saying `item.Text = nick` it should be the same with all the leading/trailing spaces intact.